# Is there a flash gallery that works alike IKEA?

Tags: flash, popup, gallery, interactive

My client want to archive the same functionality product preview as this one:

http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/categories/departments/laundry

I've searched a lot but end up find nothing that flash component or even look a like one.

Any ideas? I really need your helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IKEA used [iMapBuilder](http://www.imapbuilder.com/customization/samples.php?sampleid=floorplan)
I don't know what your budget is but it might be cheaper to just hire a flasher to code it for you
Good Luck!